# How to place a ad banner in unity using Unity ads? No plugins download

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, ads, banner

Im tying to figure out how to place an ad banner in unity but all the topics are about admobs banner in unity. I want to know how to use Unity ads banner.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

using UnityEngine;

public class UnityAdManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string gameId = "gameid";

    public string placementId = "Adbanner";

    public bool testMode = true;

    public static UnityAdManager instance;

    void Awake()
    {
        DontDestroyOnLoad(this.gameObject);
        if (instance == null)
        {
            instance = this;
        }
        else
        {
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
        }
    }
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize(gameId, testMode);
        StartCoroutine(ShowBannerWhenReady());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    public void ShowAd()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("Adcount"))
        {
            //number of ads
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Adcount") == 2)
            {




                if (Advertisement.IsReady("video"))
                {
                    Advertisement.Show("video");
                }


                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Adcount", 0);

            }
            else
            {
                PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Adcount", PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Adcount") + 1);
            }
        }

        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Adcount", 0);
        }
    }
    IEnumerator ShowBannerWhenReady()
    {
        while (!Advertisement.IsReady(placementId))
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
        }
        Advertisement.Banner.Show(placementId);
    }
}
```

**i keep getting the error

Error   CS0117  'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'Banner'
**
EDIT: I got it working in test mode but when the I try it on my phone nothing pops up. I checked around and this problem has been happening to other people. I live in the US, so this feature should be working. Other people reccomend to use another type of ads. But unity ads is very convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Banner ad example from [Unity Docs:](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity?&_ga=2.244707973.1496305119.1567047463-232178765.1533241980#banner-ads)

> ```
> using System.Collections;
> using UnityEngine;
> using UnityEngine.Advertisements;
>
> public class BannerAdScript : MonoBehaviour {
>
>     public string gameId = "1234567";
>     public string placementId = "bannerPlacement";
>     public bool testMode = true;
>
>     void Start () {
>         Advertisement.Initialize (gameId, testMode);
>         StartCoroutine (ShowBannerWhenReady ());
>     }
>
>     IEnumerator ShowBannerWhenReady () {
>         while (!Advertisement.IsReady (placementId)) {
>             yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
>         }
>         Advertisement.Banner.Show (placementId);
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: I follwed that outline but nothing pops up. But when i test it on the computer it shows thhat the ad should be working.

Comment: Have you followed the [instructions](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityAds.html) on how to set up the Unity ads? You need to register and configure the ads before they start working. Also often when it comes to ads they don't show on the device after some time or the app is in fact published. They don't want fake ad views. You should be able to get test ads. Check the instructions and Unity tutorials on their official page. Everything is well explained.

Comment: I have to Install SDK plugin to make my banner ads work?

Comment: Point 3 of the preparations: "Download and import the latest Unity Ads SDK." Also "Unity recommends always using the latest Ads SDK." It is made by Unity for Unity and is a part of the Unity Ads.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I got the testing part working but still not working on a phone. I install the required plugins and got my other ads to work. But the banner is still not showing.

Comment: now its just Advertisement.Show(placementId); But how do I change the size and position of the Banner? Since there is no "Banner" class in the Advertisement anymore?

Comment: @Suisse I can't see any information about Banner class being removed. It is still in official Admob documentation [here](https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/unity/integration-guide-unity?&_ga=2.244707973.1496305119.1567047463-232178765.1533241980#banner-ads) updated on 7th May 2020. Also I believe they wouldn't remove it for backwards compatibility.